# serve static views from subdirs using a single controller in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, static-pages

If have some static pages in a tree structure. The ones at the first level are served using static_pages_controller.rb and in my routes.rb I have :

```
get '/static_pages/news'  , :to => 'static_pages#news'  , :as => 'news'
get '/static_pages/index' , :to => 'static_pages#index' , :as => 'index'
....
```

The above exist in

```
app\views\static_pages\news.html.erb
app\views\static_pages\index.html.erb
....
```

Now, I pasted some other static pages underneath the static_pages root:

```
app\views\static_pages\ermis\news.html.erb
app\views\static_pages\ermis\index.html.erb
....
```

I added in routes.rb this:

```
get '/static_pages/ermis/news'  , :to => 'static_pages#news'    , :as => 'news'
get '/static_pages/ermis/index' , :to => 'static_pages#index'   , :as => 'index'
```

The above doesnt work because the actions already exist (parent folders). So I went the painful step of renaming the files to (there must be a better way though?!?)

```
app\views\static_pages\ermis\ermisnews.html.erb
app\views\static_pages\ermis\ermisindex.html.erb
....
```

and my routes.rb became

```
get '/static_pages/ermis/news' , :to => 'static_pages#ermisnews' , :as => 'ermisnews'
get '/static_pages/ermis/index', :to => 'static_pages#ermisindex', :as => 'ermisindex'
....
```

the controller is empty

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
end
```

Why cant the pages be served ? what am I missing?

When I click on

```
<%= link_to("Ermis", ermisnews_path, class: 'pictureTitle') %>
```

I get

```
"The action 'ermisnews' could not be found for StaticPagesController"
```

Here my routes.rb

```
Prefix Verb    URI Pattern                                Controller#Action
root           GET    /                                   static_pages#index
ermisindex     GET    /static_pages/ermis/index(.:format) static_pages#ermisindex
ermisnews      GET    /static_pages/ermis/news(.:format)  static_pages#ermisnews
news           GET    /static_pages/news(.:format)        static_pages#news
index          GET    /static_pages/index(.:format)       static_pages#index
```

NOTE: I do not get an error when using link directly pointing to .erb files on static_pages

```
<%= link_to("News"     , news_path          , class: 'pictureTitle')

Question: 
1) How can I use the same controller to also serve static pages underneath /static_pages eg. /static_pages/ermis 
2) Am I obliged to actually rename the files to have them represent unique actions?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found a solution to my issue:

1. created the following namespace:

   namespace :sp do
      resources: ixanos
      resources: ermis
   end
2. created the following controllers

   class Sp::IxanosController < ApplicationController
   end

   class Sp::ErmisController < ApplicationController
   end
3. Placed the controllers under app/controllers/sp/
4. Created the directories app/views/sp/ixanos and app/views/sp/ermis and copied my files in them.

(*) This way I can have as many static pages as I want underneath the given roots (ermis and ixanos). I haven't tested the situation whereby I will have sub-directories like sp/ermis/dir1/dir2 ...

Answer (score 0):

In route.rb, change your routes as:

```
  resources :static_pages do

    resources :ermis do

      get 'ermisnews' , :on => :collection

    end

  end

  match '/ermisnews'  => 'static_pages#ermisnews', :as => :news
```

And then run rake routes.

Comment: In my application ermis is not a sub-resource of static_pages.